# AttributeError: 'NotFound' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

When a user goes on my flask app with a URL that has more than 3 sub paths, like "domain.com/var1/var2/var3/var4", it throws the error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1478, in    full_dispatch_request
response = self.make_response(rv)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1574, in make_response
rv = self.response_class(rv, headers=headers, status=status)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 758, in __init__
self.status = status
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 862, in _set_status
self._status = to_native(value)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/_compat.py", line 111, in to_native
return x.encode(charset, errors)
AttributeError: 'NotFound' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

It works fine for url's that have less than or equal to 3 subpaths like "domain.com/var1/var2/var3", but I have routes for url's with 1, 2, and 3 subpaths.

How can I get my app to go to the 404 Page Not Found method instead of throwing this error?

Thank you!

edit..
Here's a pastebin of the route methods I'm using. http://pastebin.com/kjYsqk9n

Sorry I can't provide an example of this problem, it's really weird and I don't know how to reproduce it myself. My other flask apps work fine, this one doesn't. If anyone needs clarification, please let me know... thanks for all your help!

Comment: I think we'd need to see a little more of your flask code to be able to say anything with certainty -- could you possibly post the relevant bits? Some part of your view code maybe?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I put the relevant flask code in a pastebin: http://pastebin.com/kjYsqk9n

Comment: Thanks! Do 404s happen normally when you navigate to other non-existing pages?

Comment: @Walker, I don't think so, for example if you visit a /<country>/<state> page, in the route method I use libraries to see if that country and state exists, if not, I return page_not_found(). But it only returned 404 because I told it to. So besides the route methods that I created, the 404's do not happen and throws the error above.

Comment: I remember reading about how apache prohibits werkzeug from working (or something like that) which is why the stack trace doesn't display on apache ran servers, is that possibly why it is not working? (sorry if I'm not making sense, just recalling from a long time ago)

Comment: Is that is the complete traceback?

Comment: Yes, this is the complete traceback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out why it was returning that error. It turns out I was passing in the error object instead of "404" at the end of this line:

```
return render_template("error.html", usa=usa, canada=canada, breadcrumbs=breadcrumbs, error_code=e), 404
```

Thanks!